# cracks/marks on basement wall

Tags: walls, basement, water-damage, patching-drywall, cracks

While cleaning my basement today i saw these cracks/marks on the wall. When i touch it its dry and not wet.
Since its the basement the other side of the wall is exterior under ground.
Any idea what is causing these cracks and how to avoid them ?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That sure looks like water damage to me.  Even though it's dry now, is it possible that there is water on the outside of the wall that is infiltrating?

Comment: "Bubbling paint" is the term you are looking for.  When the paint is pushed out so there is a void behind it, we would call that a bubble.  And as jwh mentioned, its normally caused by water pushing through the wall behind the paint.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how i can fix this (since its the basement and underground).